# conectar db con fastapi

Tags: python, postgresql, aws, fastapi

estoy desarrolando una api con FastAPI en python pero la forma en que me conecto a la database es la siguiente:
Tengo unn archivo database.py con el siguiente comando:

```
import psycopg2


connection = psycopg2.connect(host='fintech.cjk3n4fypozw.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com', port=5432, database="postgres", user="****", password="****")
```

Luego en los servicios me conecto a la Db de la siguiente manera

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

con esto ejecuto todos los sql que necesite pero el problema es que pongo a andar el servidor local con uvicorn y despues de un poco tiempo me indica que la conexión se cerro, como puedo evitar que esta se cierre?